# Adding Web Reference to a secure http web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF client from which  i am supposed to communicate to a thirdparty web service whose  url and wsdl is disclosed.The third party WebService(.asmx) uses https. All I am doing is trying to add service reference from my dev environment ,but unable to succeed.So i went ahead and used SOAPUI to test the service where i am able to fire a request and got a response.

Is it not possible in VS2010 to add the service reference in order to access the metadata of a HTTPS web service ? Since this is the first time I am using HTTPS ,i would be glad if some one can guide me the right way ?

Comment: What happens when you are "unable to succeed"?

Comment: @JohnSaunders :It gives me the error "Certificate mismatch" for the url i am accessing.

Comment: What happens when you try to access that URL in your browser?

Comment: I can browse the wsdl from url.

Comment: Then please do a "File->Save As" to a disk file, and do the "Add Service Reference" pointing to the file.

Comment: Certificate mismatch. That suggests that the URL that the SSL certificate is different from the URL used to access the server. Try going to the same address using a web browser and tell us if a warning shows up.

Comment: @John Saunders:I followed your suggestion but it doesn't let me add the reference.I gives me the same error.

Comment: @Aron :I tried to get the same by using a web browser and i selected proceed anyway option then it takes me to the WSDL page.

Comment: Then save the WSDL to disk and try adding the reference to the disk location. That should work if the WSDL is all in one piece. If not, then it may reference some XSD files, in which case, again, grab them with the browser.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Saving the wsdl to a file to disk did the trick.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> @Aron :I tried to get the same by using a web browser and i selected proceed anyway option then it takes me to the WSDL page.

I will assume that you are running your development server on your local dev machine. You should check the actual address that the IIS server is setup for. Open up the page in your web browser. You will have a page that asks you if you want to proceed anyway, DONT.
View server certificate.

[image: Google mail Certificate]

Here is the GMail certificate. Notice the "issued to:". This means that the certificate is only for https://mail.google.com. If another server tried to use it for another address you would have the same error.

So you want to use whatever is in there as your https://{my issued to}/Webservice.asmx